# Configuring MySQL 5.7 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: server, upgrade, mysql

**Background**

`/etc/mysql/my.cnf` is a symbolic link to `/etc/alternatives/my.cnf`

`/etc/alternatives/my.cnf` is mostly comments, but has this at the bottom:

```
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
```

`/etc/mysql/conf.d/` has the files: `mysql.cnf` and `mysqldump.cnf`
`/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/` has the files: `mysqld.cnf` and `mysqld_safe_syslog.cnf`

I've found that `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` holds the configurations that I previously would in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`.

**Observations and Questions**

It appears to me that these changes are an attempt to modularize the MySQL configuration. In order to maintain that modularization, it seems that the best practice would be to add an new file, `overrides.cnf`, to the `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/` directory, which contains only the configuration options that I want to add and change.

Am I on the correct path here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going about this as I described. As a side effect, I really like how few directives are in the `overrides.cnf` file.